# "this kind of question" or "this kind of questions"

Tags: word-usage

Google Ngram gives this plot

[image]

It seems that "this kind of question" is more common. I guess I could deduce that "this kind of **question**" is more idiomatic than "this kind of **questions**".

The question is whether both are grammatical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical, but the expression with plural "questions" seems unnecessary, since a "kind of question" can refer to any number of questions.